# symfony factory pass custom parameters for use after persist - ZenstruckFoundryBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

**EDIT**

Forgot to include the package i am using: https://symfony.com/bundles/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/current/index.html

I am trying to figure out how i can pass extra data to the factory to use afer persist in some custom code.

I have a factory that generates a University, and after that is inserted in the database i need to then use the Course factory to assign courses which i want to do in afterPersist.

I have tried to add my own method to set the array of courses on the object:

```
/**
     * @param array $courses
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCourses(array $courses) : self
    {

        $this->courses = $courses;
        return $this;
    }
```

And then call it like this:

```
foreach($this->universities as $university){
            UniversityFactory::new()->setCourses($university['courses'])->create([
                'name'=>$university['name'],
                'slug'=>$university['slug']
            ]);
        }
```

However, i end up with an empty array in the afterPersists (this->courses is empty):

```
return $this->afterPersist(function(University $university){
            
            foreach($this->courses as $type => $courseName){
                CourseFactory::new()->create([
                    'name'=>$courseName,
                    'type'=>$type,
                    'uni'=>$university
                ]);
            }
        });
```

The array of courses does get assigned, but when running create() it gets emptied.

Comment: So where exactly do these factories come from?  I'm guessing you are using some other 3rd party admin type software?

Comment: @Cerad apologies, i'm using this package: https://symfony.com/bundles/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/current/index.html

Comment: Okay.  Not at all familiar with that package.  Factories with static methods are somewhat unusual on the Symfony eco-system.  Might see if there is a stackoverflow tag for it. If not then you might be better off finding either a Zenstruck specific support forum or maybe even opening an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit 2

Dont forget to:

- remove the code of `$this->afterPersist`
- use `Course` entity class namespace in the `University` class file
- update what you pass to `setCourses`:

```php
foreach($this->universities as $university){
    UniversityFactory::new()->setCourses(
        array_map(function ($type,$courseName){
            return (new Course())->setType($type)->setName($courseName);
        }, array_keys($university['courses']), array_values($university['courses']))
    )->create([
        'name'=>$university['name'],
        'slug'=>$university['slug']
    ]);
}
```

### Edit 1

You can actualy handle persisting courses with their `uni` relation without using `afterPersist` hook. you can just set `cascade={"persist"}` as in below and assign `uni` of each course to `$this` in the university `setCourses` Method

```php
    /**
     * @param Course[] $courses
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCourses(array $courses) : self
    {
        $this->courses = [];
        foreach($courses as $course){
            if (!$this->courses->contains($course)) {
                $this->courses[] = $course;
                $course->setUni($this);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

### Original Ansewar

Based on the fact that the `$courses` property is set but not persised
Its most likely you forgot to add `cascade={"persist"}` in the doctrine relation annotation

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(... cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private Collection|array $courses;
```

More about [Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

Comment: no i don't mean it doesn't persist to the database? this is a factory i'm talking about not an entity, i am trying to pass the courses array to the factory for use after persist of the university entity

Comment: @MMMWeirdo did you try to pass them in the array to `UniversityFactory::new()->create` just like the `name` and the `slug`

Comment: No because you pass them there and they get persisted when it creates the new record, those are instead of the defaults in the factory. None of the course data needs to be persisted at that point, i am wanting to pass it through to the factory so i can loop and create the course entities after the university is persisted. Hence my loop in: return $this->afterPersist(function(University $university){ . I'm not sure you're understanding what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Now I understand you! I'll update my answer

Comment: No you're definitely misunderstanding, i should have mentioned i am using this factory package: ZenstruckFoundryBundle

Comment: You cant use an entity class as a local store for data that are not persisted. if I understood you well you want to create a `University` object along with some `Course` objects which are stored as an array of key/type => value/name right?

Comment: If so the code above will work for you